# How do you Infer the type of an Action<T> dynamically?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a dictionary as below:

```
var composEvents = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
{
    { 
        typeof (GetWorkflowAnalysisDealLevelViewDataCompletedEvent),
        new Action<bool>(GetWorkflowAnalysisDealLevelViewDataCompleted)
    },{
        typeof (NoDataReturnedEvent), 
        new Action<NoDataReturnedParameters>(NoDataReturned)
    }
};
```

I am then subscribing to different events passing the actions as the callback however as the type of each action is different for each event i.e:

```
 Action<bool>
 Action<NoDataReturnedParameters>
```

how can I produce the below code dynamically and without explicitly casting the action type?

```
foreach (var cEvent in composEvents)
{
    var method = typeof(IEventAggregator).GetMethod("GetEvent", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(cEvent.Key);
    dynamic evt = generic.Invoke(_eventAggregator, null);
    var cancelationToken = evt.Subscribe((Action<bool>)cEvent.Value);
    _compositeEvents.Add(evt, cancelationToken);
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of the `evt.Subscribe` method?

Comment: The Subscribe method gets an Action<object>

Comment: Then you probably need to change your dictionary to be of type `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`.  Unless you can change that method.

Comment: the problem is not the signature of the Dictionary, I have tried that also but by the time we use the action in the Subscribe method it cannot infer the correct type for the action -- please see the updated question

Comment: Could you tell us in plain english what it is you want to do?  What problem is your above code meant to solve?  There is probably a better way.

Comment: Type inference stops as soon as you use `dynamic`. Declare your dictionary as Trevor Elliot described, and replace the `dynamic` by `var`.

Comment: That's not an option I am afraid as changing dynamic to var breaks the evt.Subscribe

Comment: Being able to "infer" the type means to know the type _at compile time_. You clearly don't so what you're trying to do is a nonstarter.

Comment: But I do know the type of the action as it's being defined as the Value in the Dictionary e.g.     new Action<NoDataReturnedParameters>(NoDataReturned)

Comment: But the compiler doesn't - it knows that the dict contains `<Type, Delegate>` as key/value so it can only assume that these are the types of objects that are present - it can't make any further assumption about the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will achieve your intended result:

```
public abstract class Base 
{
    public abstract void Assign ( object value );
}

public class Assigner<EventType, ActionType>: Base
{
    public override void Assign ( object value )
    {
        AssignAction((ActionType)value);
    }

    private void AssignAction ( ActionType action )  
    {
        var event = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<EventType>();
        var token = event.Subscribe(action);
        _compositeEvents.Add(event, token);
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
foreach (var cEvent in composEvents)
{
    var genericType = typeof(Assigner<,>).MakeGenericType(cEvent.Key, cEvent.Value.GetType());
    var assignerInstance = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
    assignerInstance.Assign(cEvent.Value);
}
```

Please be aware I typed all of code directly here, so there are probably syntax errors, typos, and accidental misdirection.

I believe that will work, if it doesn't: feel free to let me know.

The `Assigner` type is making use of _compositeEvents and _eventAggregator that it doesn't have access to (most likely), so you'll need to either pass them in to the constructor or make them accessible from somewhere.

You will need to add some constraints to the generic type parameters, because `GetEvent()` has them, but hopefully those will be relatively obvious.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an `Action<T>` and you need to turn it into an `Action<object>`.  In order to do this the method will, by necessity, fail at runtime if the object isn't of the proper type `T`.  There's no real way around that.  You can use `DynamicInvoke` to attempt to invoke the delegate with the given object.  If it's of the right type it will work, if it's not, it won't:

```
public static Action<object> Foo(Delegate del)
{
    return obj => del.DynamicInvoke(obj);
}
```